# How to get the SQL for a data source

Tags: tableau-api

I have "inherited" a set of Tableau workbooks and dashboards. No documents around how the data sources are built. I am familiar with databases and tables but how the SQLs and/or logic behind the data sources.

In order to troubleshoot and answer questions I am getting how can I figure out the data source details (SQLs).

I saw some answers around looking at the log files after data source refresh etc but do not have access to the Tableau server.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Posting here just in case someone would have the same question in the future

The data source was a published data source, I had to right-click on it and create a local copy. After that since database was behind a jumpbox I had to create an SSH tunnel to connect to database using local data source and was able to see the custom SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It is also posible to see the emitted SQL for a Tableau workbook by turning on performance monitoring from the `Help|Settings and Performance|Start Performance Recording` menu. This records all queries and generates a workbook containing the queries and analysis of which things took what time in the original Table workbook.